# One label for multiple points

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel

I'm making a scatterplot and want to label several points with the same label.

```
data.frame(label=rep(c("a","b","c"),2), x=rep(c(1:3),2), y=(5,4,7,2,6,9))
```

As you can see, the labels occur twice each at the same x values, only y differs. I want both `[1,5]` and `[1,2]` to be labeled using a single "a", not one "a" for each coordinate.

I'm using R, ggplot2 and ggrepel.

[image]

Comment: I guess I'm a little confused...if you only want one label, why not just use the first half of your dataframe?

Comment: Because y is different. Its not the same point. Two points share the same label.

Comment: Can you show a picture of what you want?

Comment: Please see update.

Comment: For anyone interested, [here is a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77642747/2530121) I created for a similar question. It doesn't use `ggrepel`, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

This can work:

```
dat <- data.frame(label=rep(c("a","b","c"),2), x=rep(c(1:3),2), y=c(5,4,7,2,6,9))

ggplot() + geom_point(data=dat, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_text(data=dat[duplicated(dat$label),], aes(x=x, y=y, label=label))
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but this deletes half the data and only labels the remaining one point. One label should point toward two points.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.

I am using the dplyr or tidyverse package.

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Dataset

```
dat1 <- data.frame(label=rep(c("a","b","c"),2), x=rep(c(1:3),2), y=c(5,4,7,2,6,9))
```

Creating a dataset for the labels. This creates a label dataset which will pick a labeling point at midpoint Y for a given X.

```
lab1 <- dat1 %>% group_by(label) %>% mutate(x = x, y = mean(y))
```

This creates the plot using the original dataset for the points and the label dataset for the labels.

```
ggplot() + 
geom_point(data=dat1, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
geom_text(data=lab1, aes(x=x, y=y, label=label), size = 5) +
theme_grey()
```

[image: One Label!]

The above actually plots the labels twice on top of each other, but you can't notice. If you really just wanted it once, then you could do the following and update the previous code with lab2. I also changed size so you can see.

```
lab2 <-unique(lab1)

ggplot() + 
geom_point(data=dat1, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
geom_text(data=lab2, aes(x=x, y=y, label=label), size=10) +
theme_grey()
```

If you wanted the x direction more to the right or higher, you could update your label dataset by adding an offset to your label dataset.

```
lab1 <- dat1 %>% group_by(label) %>% mutate(x = x+.3, y = mean(y) + .5)
```

Or you can accomplish the same within geom_text itself using nudge.

```
ggplot() + geom_point(data=dat1, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
geom_text(data=lab1, aes(x=x, y=y, label=label), size=10, nudge_x = .3, nudge_y = .5) + 
theme_grey()
```

[image: Label With Offset]

Comment: Thats an ok solution, but is it not possible to use ggrepel and get arrows/lines pointing towards the points? This is a simplified plot, what if it has hundreds of data points?

Comment: If this has hundreds of data points then you wouldn't want to do the plot you suggest. Why would you want to label many points with one label and many lines? It would be much better to just use the fill color to have the same "labeled" points be the same color and then your legend will have the label for you.

Comment: Sorry, but that comment is very ignorant. Also, when a question is asked, the solution for the question should be presented, not something entirely different.