# Multiple points with same label in ggrepel - avoid redundant labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text, annotate, ggrepel

I want to annotate a scatterplot with several points that have the same label. I want to label all of them (not just a part of them) but it is a mess with so many redundant labels.
Is there any way to have one single label pointing to all the points with the same label with ggrepel::geom_text_repel?

I attach the simplest possible situation:

```
df <- data.frame(
  group = c("A", "A", "B", "B"),
  x = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  y = c(2, 3, 4, 5)
)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text_repel(data=df, aes(label=group), box.padding = 0.5, force = 4)
```

Now:
[image]

What I want:
[image]

PS: @user2862862 posted the same question in 2019 but there was no proper answer in [One label for multiple points](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56820888/17195896)

Comment: Instead of posting the same question again, I would rather put a bounty on the old one.

Comment: I get the feeling that solving this would lead to an even worse plot. It would be fine for your example, but once you have several points, it's going to look incredibly messy. In general, I'm a fan of directly labelled plots, but where many points are labelled, it is often more elegant to use point color or shape to denote groupings. Could you give us a more realistic data sample? I can think of several possible solutions that might work here, but they are very dependent on the number of points.

Comment: This is interesting... I could imagine computing a summary data set with average x/y values for each group, then using geom_text_repel to label each group perhaps [using blank labels](https://ggrepel.slowkow.com/articles/examples.html#hide-some-of-the-labels) for the actual points, and then extracting the text coords and going back to draw the lines.... it would take some doing.

Comment: @GregorThomas that was exactly my thought too, but it won't work. The selective randomness in ggrepel is generated at draw time, with a `makeContent` mechanism on a bespoke grob. Neither a `ggplot_build` nor even a `ggplot_gtable` will contain the co-ordinates of the label - only the point from which the label is repelled. This is necessary because the labels need to repel appropriately when the plot is different sizes.

Comment: One option would be be to add the label and segments/arrows on separate plot layers. With precomputation this should work without using repulsion. I am not sure if it will work cleanly of not but package 'ggpp' provides function `position_nudge_to()` which could provide a different workaround. You can either force `geom_text_repel()` not to apply any repulsion, or you could use `geom_text_s()` from 'ggpp' which draws the segment based on nudging but does not apply any repulsion. Neither of these approaches uses repulsion, so both approaches need manual tweaking of the locations of the labels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an approach to achieve what you want. However, as @AllanCameron alluded to in the comments, the appropriateness of this approach is *heavily* data dependent. I have included extra examples to illustrate potential issues.

This method involves computing the mean xy for each group, then creating two more dataframes: one for the lines (df1), and one for the labels (df2):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Your example data (Example1): IMPORTANT: note modified x and y column names,
# you will first need to change your x and y columns to x_1 and y_1
df <- data.frame(
  group = c("A", "A", "B", "B"),
  x_1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  y_1 = c(2, 3, 4, 5)
)

# Create df for plotting lines from original points to group's mean point
df1 <- df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(x_2 = mean(x_1),
         y_2 = mean(y_1)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-group,
               names_to = c(".value", "var"),
               names_sep = "_")

# Create df for single group label
df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(x_2 = mean(x_1),
         y_2 = mean(y_1)) %>%
  select(-ends_with("1")) %>%
  distinct()

# Plot
ggplot() +
  geom_path(data = df1,
            aes(x, y, group = group),
            colour = "grey") +
  geom_point(data = df,
             aes(x_1, y_1),
             size = 2) +
  geom_text(data = df2,
            aes(x_2, y_2, label = group),
            size = 5)
```

Now consider these two other example dataframes:

```
# Example2
df <- data.frame(
  group = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 3),
  x_1 = c(1, 1.5, 2, 3, 3.5, 4),
  y_1 = c(2, 4, 3, 4, 2.5, 5)
)

# Example3
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(group = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 10),
                 x_1 = runif(n = 30, min = 1, max = 4),
                 y_1 = runif(n = 30, min = 2, max = 5))
```

[image: first examples]

Example1 and Example2 look ok, but your proposed method doesn't scale nicely for data like Example3. Lines for each group cross and this makes it difficult to interpret. If your full data are more complex and contain lots of points like Example3, using colour (or shape) is much more effective at communicating what is going on in your data:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = df,
             aes(x_1, y_1, colour = group),
             size = 2) +
  labs(x = "x", y = "y")
```

[image: colour example]

Comment: You are right, with many point it doesn't look ok either. In addition, in my case (that you correctly assumed it is more complex) it is also based in a geom_jitter, which would make any attempts to have one label for multiple points impossible.
Anyway coloring or shape is a better idea as you suggested.